# C wird zu Z ...?

Tags: spelling, evolution

Ich habe letztens `Zenter` auf einem offiziellen Schild gelesen. Ist das korrekt?

`Zentrum` gibt es ja nun schon einige Jahrzehnte als Nachfolger von `Centrum`. Daran hab mich mich dann auch gewöhnt. Muss ich das nun auch in diesem Fall tun?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zenter ist falsch, [Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Zenter) hat dazu auch keinen Eintrag.
Aber es scheint die [mittelhochdeutsche Version von Zentrum](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zentrum) zu sein.

> Zentrum, das
>
> ...
>
> Herkunft
>
> **mittelhochdeutsch zenter** < lateinisch centrum = Mittelpunkt < griechisch kéntron, eigentlich = Stachel(stab); ruhender Zirkelschenkel, zu: kenteĩn = (ein)stechen

[Center](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Center_Einkaufszentrum) wiederum ist englischen, bzw. französischen Ursprungs.

Comment: Evtl. ist der Lexer eine noch bessere Quelle für Mittelhochdeutsch ([**zënter**](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=BZ00335&sigle=BMZ)).

Comment: Im *Mittelhochdeutschen* gabs das? Das finde ich jetzt spannend; denn ich lass es in der (Deutsch-)Schweiz.

Comment: @alk Könnte es sich dabei um einen Eigennamen gehandelt haben, in dem die ursprüngliche Schreibweise erhalten blieb?

Comment: @Takkat: Hmm, gute Frage, ich weiss nicht mehr, was da benannt wurde. Sollte ich nochmal vorbeikommen, prüf ich das.